# How to remove file attributes?

Tags: gnome, files, gvfs

The Arch Linux version of gio has a set command that has a -d option to remove an attribute:
https://man.archlinux.org/man/gio.1

But this set command delete option did not work when I tried it in Ubuntu. And the Ubuntu manual does not list this option, or any other option, to remove an attribute using the set command:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/gio.1.html

So how are attributes removed in Ubuntu?

The commands that did not work are:

```
gio set -d "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::gedit-encoding"
gio set -d "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::gedit-position"
gio set -d "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::gedit-spell-language"
gio set -d "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::nautilus-drop-position"
gio set -d "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::nautilus-icon-position"
```

The response to each of them is this error:

```
gio: Unknown option -d
```

Comment: I see different versions here. Have you looked for changelogs? Or the different patches that Debian and Arch apply during build and packaging?

Comment: What exact command line are you trying?

Comment: To answer your question I edited in the commands you asked for to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Following your examples, you can use

```
gio set --type=unset "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::gedit-encoding"
```

According to the [Arch Linux man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/gio.1) you linked in your question

```
-d, --delete
   Unsets an attribute (same as setting it's type to unset).
```

does the same as `--type=unset`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. What worked is `gio set --type=unset` . What did not work is `gio set -t=unset` , which as far as I can see should have. But what matters is I have a way that works. :)

Comment: @Stephen You should try `-t unset`, this way other commands handle it for the short option. Example from `man grep`: `-f FILE, --file=FILE`.